# Is it possible to connect a motor to a spike hub without connecting the cables?

Tags: spike-prime

I know it sounds foolish but can I?

I've tried Robot Inventor, but it just doesn't connect and doesn't work.

Comment: Hi cnvıkyghb and welcome to Bricks.SE! Please note that this is a Q&A site, where volunteer participants take their time to share their knowledge with askers, since they believe in the value of sharing and helping. Please show your respect to these people and this idea by taking your time to properly spell and format your messages here, if you wish to participate in this community. If you plan on staying, I'd recommend that you read the [tour] and [help] pages to get acquainted. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Without cables, no electric current can flow so the motors would not be powered. Wireless power transmission at such wattage levels is not yet part of LEGO's technology stack and probably won't be for a long time. Wireless control would be possible though, but that would still necessitate some kind of power supply at the motors (batteries, mains converter, or such).